# NGINX and Chrome

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, web-server

Going a bit mad here, pulling my hair out.
The site on http://alpha.draser.co.uk works on IE and Firefox (only tested those) and doesn't work on Chrome. I've tested this on my computer and a remote server and the same issue occurs.

alpha.draser.co.uk config

```
server {
    listen 37.230.100.89:80;
    root /var/www/draser/alpha/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name alpha.draser.co.uk;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}`
```

draser.co.uk config

```
server {
    listen 37.230.100.89:80;

    if ($http_referer ~* (buttons-for-website.com)) { return 444; }

    server_name www.draser.co.uk draser.co.uk;
    return 301 https://draser.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 37.230.100.89:443 ssl;

    if ($http_referer ~* (buttons-for-website.com)) { return 444; }

    root /var/www/draser/live/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.draser.co.uk draser.co.uk;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/draser/draser.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/draser/draser.key;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

`

Edit: Tested all 3 browsers on both PCs. Tried clearing the Chrome cache to no avail.

Comment: What exactly happens when you load the page in Chrome?

Comment: It attempts to load alpha.draser over HTTPS, so it throws an invalid certificate warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `alpha.draser.co.uk` hitting SSL is this definition:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains";
```

This tells browser always to use HTTPS to connect to any subdomain of `draser.co.uk`. You have received this setting from the server on the first occasion when you have requested `https://draser.co.uk`.

This is a security feature on SSL/TLS connections.

Another problem in the configuration:

Your certificate file is missing the intermediate certificate from StartCom, as indicated by [Qualys SSL Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=draser.co.uk).

So, you need to download http://www.startssl.com/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.pem and add it after the certificate in draser.crt file.

Comment: The address alpha.draser.co.uk should not be hitting any SSL.

Comment: This is separate. You have no default server for SSL connections, so nginx passes all unknown hos requests to the first SSL server entry, which then returns draser.co.uk site. You cannot really avoid this behavior, unless you host `alpha.draser.co.uk` on some other IP address.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to http://alpha.draser.co.uk, not an SSL connection. Chrome, unlike Firefox and IE, tries to connect to the SSL connection, which of course will make that error. My question is, why does Chrome, unlike other browsers, think that is an SSL connection?

Comment: Updated answer with the answer to this question.

Comment: I see. So removing "includeSubDomains" should resolve the problem? Also, why does this only work on Chrome? Also, I know about the certificate chain, just want to get the subdomain working at the moment.

Comment: Removing "includeSubDomains" does not solve the problem. Tested on local machine and remote machine.

Comment: Yep I have. Even setting max-age=0 doesn't solve the problem. Is it just currently a caching issue?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a caching issue as Chrome works on my phone. Thanks everyone.

Comment: This works on any browsers. However, you might have only accessed `draser.co.uk` without the `www` prefix only on Chrome. That's why it is the only one that applies the setting to every subdomain.